# yticklabels only at major ticks matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a problem regarding yticklabels in matplotlib.

I' m trying to make a vertical barplot (plt.barh) and then trying to use ax.set_yticklabels command.
The problem that I have is that it only puts the labels at the major ticks! The list that I'm passing is of length 18, however it only labels 10 of the bars!!

Help please?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you need to set `yticks` before you set `yticklabels`:

```
from numpy import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()

ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
x=random.uniform(0,5,size=5)

#plot
ax.barh(arange(len(x)),x,1)

#set ticks
T=arange(len(x))+0.5
ax.set_yticks(T)

#set labels
labels=['a','b','c','d','e']
ax.set_yticklabels(labels)

plt.show()
```

Comment: You can even do a small trick here - first do `yticks = ax.get_yticks()` and then `ax.set_yticks(yticks)` and after that the `ax.set_yticklabels()` will work :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `set_yticks`, but passing the argument `minor` `True` or `False`:

```
majorticks = [1., 2., 3.]
minorticks = [1.5, 2.5]
ax.set_yticks( minorticks, minor=True )
ax.set_yticks( majorticks, minor=False ) # The default in version 1.3.0
```

The same works for `set_yticklabels`...